# MATLAB: How to create structure fields with a name defined by a string.

Tags: matlab, structure

I have a constructor like this:

```
function p = class_name(folder, file_name)

    xmlfile = fullfile(folder, file_name);
    xDoc = xmlread(xmlfile);

        struct = xml2struct(xDoc);

        %lots of repetitive code

end
```

It reads and XML file and transforms it into a struct. The struct elements are then assign to the class's properties/fields using some repetitive code like this:

```
if(isfield(struct.parameters, 'parameter_name'))
    p.property_name = struct.parameters.parameter_name.Text;
else
    p.property_name = '';
end
```

I would like to put this into a method/function which, given the name of the struct element (here 'parameter_name') and the name of the class field/property (here 'property_name') assigns the former to the latter.

Is it possible to write a generic function/method for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement such a function using dynamic field names. This is the [recommended](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) implementation for such cases:

```
function p = setparam(s, p, param_name, prop_name)
    if(isfield(s.parameters, param_name))
       param = s.parameters.(param_name);
       p.(prop_name) = param.Text;
    else
       p.(prop_name) = '';
    end
end
```

You can also use setfield and getfield on older versions of MATLAB:

```
function p = setparam(s, p, param_name, prop_name)
    if(isfield(s.parameters, param_name))
        param = getfield(s.parameters, param_name);
        p = setfield(p, prop_name, getfield(param, 'Text'));
    else
        p = setfield(p, prop_name, '');
    end
end
```

Do not use struct for structure name in your code - it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: I get a warning. Use dynamic fieldnames with structures instead of getfield/setfield. I guess that's what Nick is getting at. Could you please adapt your code? Thanks.

Comment: @csetzkorn I have updated the code. What MATLAB version are you using? I do not get a warning. Anyway, the explanation why to use dynamic fields and not getfield/setfield is some performance advantage. Whether it matters in your code depends of course, you would have to check. But getting rid of a warning is definitely a good reason to use dynamic fields.

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic field names:

```
yourStruct.parameters.('parameter_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a a generic function:
Can be used for either structs or class objects

```
function obj_to = set_props(obj_to, obj_from)
% insert properties from obj_from into obj_to. 
props_from = fieldnames(obj_from);
props_to = fieldnames(obj_to);
for k = 1 : length(props_to)
    if ismember(props_to{k}, props_from)
        obj_to.(props_to{k}) = obj_from.(props_to{k});
    else
        obj_to.(props_to{k}) = '';
    end
end
```

Now, in the constructor:

```
function obj = class_name(folder, file_name)
    xmlfile = fullfile(folder, file_name);
    xDoc = xmlread(xmlfile);
    s = xml2struct(xDoc); % do not use word "struct" for variables
    set_props(obj, s);    % if obj has handle, no need to return it from set_props()
end
```